Is there a symbolic connection between the name Lot (Λώτ) and the veil (καταπέτασμα) in the Holy of Holies?
In the Bible, Lot (Λώτ) is a significant figure from the Old Testament, particularly known for his story in Genesis 19 where he is rescued from the destruction of Sodom and Gomorrah. The name Lot in Hebrew (לוֹט) can be connected to the root meaning “covering” or “veil.”
On the other hand, the Greek term “καταπέτασμα” refers to the veil in the Temple in Jerusalem that separated the Holy of Holies from the rest of the Temple. This veil is notably mentioned in the New Testament in Matthew 27:51, where it is torn from top to bottom at the moment of Jesus’ death, symbolizing the opening of access to God for all people.
Given these details, is there a symbolic or thematic connection between Lot (as a “covering” or “veil”) and the καταπέτασμα (veil) of the Temple? How have biblical scholars and hermeneutics interpreted these potential connections, if at all?

Linguistically speaking, the two Hebrew words involved here are as follows:
פֹרֶכֶת (paroketh) = "curtain/veil" and always denotes the curtain separating the holy from the holy of holies in the sanctuary and later in the temple.  It occurs 25 times in the OT: Ex 26:31, 33, 35, 27:21, 30:6, 35:12, 36:35, 38:27, 39:34, 40:3, 21, 22, 26, Lev 4:17, 16:2, 12, 15, 21:23, 24:3, Num 4:5, 18:7, 2 Chron 3:14.
Thus, the primary function of the veil/curtain/paroketh was separating the holy place from the holy of holies.
לוֹט (Lot) = Abraham's Nephew, Lot (a proper name) and the same as the noun לוֹט (lot) = "envelope, covering".  According to BDB, this name is derived from the verb לוּט (lut) meaning "to wrap closely or tightly, enwrap, envelop" (Strong's) as per 1 Sam 21:10, 1 Kings 19:13, Isa 25:7.
It should now be obvious that "paroketh" and "lot" are not linguistically related by etymology nor semantics.
